# how to update existing table when each row to be updated is a different value

Tags: sql, postgresql

I had a `file` table which had `data` column whereby file's data was stored in bytes. For performance reasons I had to take out the data column and place that in new table called `fileData`. `file` and `fileData` table have `@OnetoOne` mapping.

```
CREATE TABLE public.file
(
  id character varying(255) NOT NULL,
  contenttype character varying(255),
  name character varying(255),
  size character varying(255),
  dataId character varying(255),
  CONSTRAINT file_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id),
  CONSTRAINT fk8af75923ef78c73c FOREIGN KEY (dataId)
      REFERENCES public.filedata (id) MATCH SIMPLE
      ON UPDATE NO ACTION ON DELETE NO ACTION
)

CREATE TABLE filedata
(
  id character varying(255) NOT NULL,
  filedata bytea,
  CONSTRAINT filedata_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id)
)
```

Now I need to port all values of data column in file table to fileData table. How can I do that? I was using stored procedure like below. But I am not sure how to update dataId for all rows of file table

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION moveDataToNewTable() RETURNS void AS 
$BODY$
DECLARE
   dataId integer;
   _r record;
BEGIN 
    dataId = 0; 
    for _r in (select * from file)  loop         
    dataId= dataId+1;  
    INSERT INTO filedata (id, data) VALUES (dataId, _r.data);  

     --update file table set dataId to current value of dataId

end loop;
    END;
    $BODY$
    LANGUAGE plpgsql VOLATILE;
```

Thanks.

Comment: `dataId= dataId+1;  ` is completely wrong as your "ids" are all strings and you can't just "add one" to a string. You have to make them `integers` if you want something like an auto-generated ID

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name . . . That is not exactly correct.  Mind you, you are totally correct that the types should not be mixed like this.  However, Postgres will attempt to implicitly convert the string to a number.  If it succeeds, then the `+ 1` will work, and the value will be re-converted for assignment.  I definitely don't approve of implicit conversions, but you can "just add one to a string", if the string represents a number.

Comment: Thanks for the comments . Agreed that calculating ids as above is not the recommended approach. I have tried another option. Instead of stored procedure I wrote a service to 'setFileData` for every attachment row, but now I am getting `Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded` whilst saving the files.

Comment: Any particular reason, you chose `file` referencing `filedata` and not the other way round? Form you description, I'd expected `filedata` refrencing `file`. And like that you could just have used the same ID values as in `file` for the corresponding rows in `filedata`.

Comment: @stickybit It would have been a better option to have same ids for `file`and `fileData`. But however I couldn't achieve that `file` because id in `file` table is  auto-generated ID and hence while saving a file object i wouldn't have its id to be assigned to `fileData`. Hence ended up having different ids for both table.

Comment: @stickybit code sample 
`public class File{
    @Id()
    @GeneratedValue(generator="file_uuid")
    @GenericGenerator(name="file_uuid", strategy = "uuid")
    private String id;

    @OneToOne(targetEntity = FileData.class, cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private FileData fileData;}` `@Entity(name = "filetData")
public class FileData implements Serializable {

    @Id()
    @GeneratedValue(generator="file_data_uuid")
    @GenericGenerator(name="file_data_uuid", strategy = "uuid")
    private String id;
 ....
    
}`

Comment: You could use Postgres' [`RETURNING`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/static/dml-returning.html) to get the value, if it was generated by the database. But maybe you're generating the ID in the client? I'm not sure, as your code is hard to read in the comment and I'm not even sure which language this is (Java?), let alone which ORM. Maybe post another question including the code, the language, the ORM, etc. to ask how to reuse the ID generated for the second insert.